# How to support Spanish and French Language in android?

Tags: android, android-configchanges

I want to change the application content from English to Spanish/ French as per the selection. Do we have any build-in libraries for the same. I am new to this multilanguage part, so please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create an additional folder like `values-fr` (for French) and provide `strings.xml` with respective values.

here you can find detailed guide:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

Answer (score 2):

Create `strings.xml(fr)` and `strings.xml(es)` with your translated strings in the respective language.

Use this library to set the language in your app, it manages all the overhead of Configuration Context and other boilerplate code

https://github.com/YarikSOffice/lingver.

This how you create multiple language resources

In android studio

- Res-> New -> Android Resource File->
- Name the file strings.xml -> Resoure Type Should be value
- Select Locale From Available Qualifiers
- Select Language and Set region to be any
- Click Ok

[image]